# how to create wokflow to auto fill title field and auto populate document into library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

would any one please help me with setting the correct workflow to create a DOC document based on the Item list filled in SharePoint 365?

I have following list and library, with the right set up of content types:
-  list called Project Status Checkpoint, where all necessary info re project update is filled by PM.
- Document library called Status Report Doc, where the created documents shall appear

As 1st step I need the workflow to fill out the "Title" field, as the PMs do not fill the title field in, this should be automatically set to "Project Status Checkpoint - [current day] - *this workflow works and the title is set in the list with no issue.*

2nd step in the workflow is, when the title field is crated, to create the document in the Status report docs library based on the information from the created list.

I have tried to set the workflow, see below, but I am receiving error on the workflow.
[image]

Unknown error:
System Account
The workflow could not create the list item. Make sure the list exists and the user has permissions to add items to the list.

I am using SharePoint designer 2013 with Sharepoint 2010 workflow platform type for this particular workflow setting.

I would really appreciate if anyone could advise me on how to create the right workflow to manage the above.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the Create item action contents to the post, and show you where the Current Day variable is coming from? Also, in your second If statement, Title will always equal Title, regardless of whether it is empty or not. Create a variable for your desired title and use it to set the title and for comparison in your second If statement. This should help narrow down the cause of your error.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the workflow is being published OK?
Maybe try changing the workflow to run as 'User who created the current item' and make sure that account has perms in the destination list/library.
Also if you've made changes to the list/library AFTER publishing the workflow, you may need to go back to the code, reselect the list, then republish the workflow.